# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '....' to data type int in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to display a list of item names alongside its respective quantities from my `OrderItem` table based on a specific `OrderID` but the query isn't working and its displaying the conversion failed error..

The query I've constructed successfully displays a list of `ItemIDs` with `quantities` but I want it to display the `ItemNames` instead. The problem is that it's only the `ItemID` that can be accessed in the `OrderItem` table.

I did a bit of digging and I tried using `INNER JOIN` but I getting this error, so I'm assuming that I'm sort of on the right track?

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'CardiVas' to
>   data type int.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    OrderItem.ItemID, 
    SUM(OrderItem.Quantity) AS NumOfOrderItems
FROM 
    OrderItem 
INNER JOIN 
    Item ON Item.Name = OrderItem.ItemID, [Order] 
WHERE 
    [OrderItem].OrderID  = [Order].OrderID
GROUP BY  
    OrderItem.ItemID;
```

Additionally, I did a bit of digging on the conversion error and tried the methods using `CONVERT` and `CASE` below but it didn't work either and I still got the same error:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), OrderItem.ItemID)
```

and

```
CASE(NVARCHAR(20, OrderItem.ItemID)
```

Can anyone give me a solution to this or perhaps a better way of displaying the data I require?

If there is any additional code or info required please let me know and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: You have a total mashup of join styles here. You have an explicit inner join and an implicit inner join too. You should always be specific with your joins. Also, don't be scared to add some white space to your queries, Formatting makes a world of difference for readability.

Comment: You're using an old style join on the [Order] table, I would consider changing this to use a proper `JOIN`

Comment: `OrderID` is in the `Order` table and in the `OrderItem` table as a foreign key. `OrderItem` is a association between `Order` and `Item` tables.

Comment: Duly noted! Thanks for the advice. @SeanLange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the `join` condition to show the names:

```
SELECT i.ItemName, SUM(oi.Quantity) AS NumOfOrderItems
FROM OrderItem oi INNER JOIN
     Item i
     ON i.ItemId = oi.ItemID
GROUP BY i.ItemName;
```

You also don't need the `Order` table to get the counts you want.  (And `Order` is a lousy name for a table because it is a SQL keyword.)

Comment: Thank you! I called it `Order` because the system is an Order-Delivery system. I'm aware of the terrible naming conventions. :(

Comment: @mustang00 . . . I name tables in the plural, which solves the problem for most tables, other than `values`, but I guess I've never had an entity called `value`.

Comment: @mustang00 since Order is really the header you could do something like OrderHead or similar. It is a bit odd but makes your life a lot easier not using reserved words.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the problem with this query is that it displays ALL the `OrderItems` when I only want it to display `Order Items` for a specific `Order`, how would the `query` change? That was the reason why I included `Order`. Apologies for not clearing that up.

Comment: @mustang00 . . . You would add a `WHERE` clause for the order `WHERE oi.OrderId = XXX`.